# ngb-calendar with alert on click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a little logical problem, i imported the ngb - calendar. I added an alert at the click of the calendar but this alert is also activated when I change the month in the calendar, how can I activate the alert only when I click on the dates?

app.component.ts:

`alert() {this.onConfirm(window.confirm('You are booking a seat  on the day' + this.model1 + ' do you want to confirm?')); }`

app,component.html:

`<ngb-datepicker #d1 [(ngModel)]="model1" #c1="ngModel" (click)="alert()" ></ngb-datepicker>`

in your opinion how can i enable the click only in the date cells or how can i remove the alert in the outside of the dates?

thanks a lot to everyone! :)